# Difference between low and high bit registers

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

"AH-DH"
The high bit AH, BH, CH, and DH registers.
"AL-DL"
The low bit AL, BL, CL, and DL registers.

It's quoted from AMD64 volume 1, also I have seen that in Intels programmer manual.
I don't clearly understand what does it mean.
Does it have anything to do with endian order? Since both amd and intel microprocessors are little-endian order.

Can it be explained as:
AH: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
Is read from the first bit so it returns: 2 (in decimal)
But the same value in
AL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
Is read from the end and it returns: 64 (in decimal)

Comment: @dhke yeah you are right edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AH is the greater half of AX, AL is the lesser half, and similarly for the B,C, and D registers. Because we are directly specifying the high order bits, or the low order bits, rather than just asking for whatever comes first, endianness doesn't really come into play.

```
         AX = 0x288
 ________|________
/                 \
0000 0010 1000 1000
\_______/ \_______/
 AH=0x2    AL=0x88
```

Comment: I think this was the answer i was looking for... nice diagram.

Answer (score 2):

The quote is from ([preface, page xxvii](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/24592_APM_v11.pdf#29)). The registers go all the way back [to the 8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Registers_and_instructions) and their behavior is still the same as back then.

The contents of the 16-bit registers `AX`, `BX`, `DX`, `CX` are also accessible using 8-bit accessors. In particular, if

```
AX = 0x1234
```

then

```
AH = 0x12
AL = 0x34
```

Hence "high" and "low" bit registers. The primary reason for these accessors to exist is to reduce instruction length. If you only need to store an 8-bit value, having to encode to full 16-bit into an instruction is wasteful.

For 32-bit and 64-bit registers, however, only the lower parts are accessible by explicit register names.

For example, `AX` is the lower part of `EAX` and `EAX` is the lower part of (64-bit) `RAX`.